# How to ZIP the downloaded file using spring boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, zip

I am beginner in java and would like some assistance with zipping a downloaded file using rest api call to MSSQL backend. Below is the code snippet which takes the ID as input parameter, fetches the record specific for that ID and downloads it locally.
I now need the code  modified to Zip the file when it is downloading.

```
@GetMapping("/message/save")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> download(@RequestParam("id") Long id) throws Exception {
        Optional<MessageEntity> messageRecord = messageRepository.findById(id);
        MessageEntity messageEntity = messageRecord.get();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String xml = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(messageEntity);
        byte[] isr = xml.getBytes();
        String fileName = "message.zip";
        HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        respHeaders.setContentLength(isr.length);
        respHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        respHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(isr, respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I expect the output to be a zipped file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood your problem clearly. But I assume that you need just make zip from string:

```
@GetMapping("/message/save")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public void download(@RequestParam("id") Long id, HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    MessageEntity messageEntity = messageRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Not found!"));
    String xml = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(messageEntity);
    String fileName = "message.zip";
    String xml_name = "message.xml";
    byte[] data = xml.getBytes();
    byte[] bytes;
    try (ByteOutputStream fout = new ByteOutputStream();
         ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout)) {
        zout.setLevel(1);
        ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(xml_name);
        ze.setSize(data.length);
        zout.putNextEntry(ze);
        zout.write(data);
        zout.closeEntry();
        bytes = fout.getBytes();
    }
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; "
                    + String.format("filename*=" + StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() + "''%s", fileName));
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    FileCopyUtils.copy(bytes, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: I apologize for not being clear on my question. Basically i need to create a GET resource to be able to take multiple input parameters (multiple IDs ex: 100,101,102 etc). My backend MSSQL server has required data. When my newly developed resource is called using GET, Database should return data for above mentioned IDs. This result should then get zipped and downloaded into my local downloads folder. I should be able to unzip the content without any errors. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your code above, the contents of the zip file looks gibberish when opened using notepad and unable to unzip the content. I get below message: unexpected end of data Warnings: There are some data after the end of the payload data. Data error: message.xml

Comment: Appreciate your help on this. Thank you.

Comment: I've changed the code a little bit (added setSize and closeEntry, please, check)

Comment: Thank you so much....How do i pass multiple IDs as parameter? At the moment it takes single ID as input parameter.

Comment: you can pass  @PathVariable("ids") String[] or Integer[] and query string would be like url/1,2,3,4  or you can make instead of GET use POST, and post json to the service

Comment: Sorry to trouble you. I am unable to get it working with my limited knowledge in java. Could you please help me with passing multiple IDs as parameter? Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.